# Changing background image of table dynamically

Tags: javascript, background-image, cells

I'm trying to change the background images of table cells with Javascript and I do so by creating the name of the image inside the code using the counter index in a for loop `(i)`

This doesn't work, can somebody explain why and how to do it properly?
If I put a static image name it works, if I try dynamically it doesn't.

**This Doesn't work:**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('SelectionBoard');
var cells = tbl.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', sbClick, false);
    var imgSrc = 'ulr(./FoodImages/fruit' + i.toString() + '.jpg)';
    cells[i].style.backgroundImage=imgSrc;
}
```

**This does:**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('SelectionBoard');
var cells = tbl.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', sbClick, false);
    var imgSrc = 'url(./FoodImages/fruit3.jpg)'; 
    cells[i].style.backgroundImage=imgSrc;
}
```

Comment: You have typo... it's not programming question...

Comment: Please stop downvoting, this one question costed me the right to ask another question on this forum. I didn't post the question lightly. I did check the code before i do that. You never had a typo that you just couldn't see? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo:

```
var imgSrc = 'ulr(./FoodImages/fruit' + i.toString() + '.jpg)';
               ^^
```

Change that to url(...)

Also the .toString() should not be necessary